# set text to alert dialog Android

Tags: android, dialog, set, alert

I want to set the text to the alert dialog but I am having some issues.

```
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        input.setText(user_descript,TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE); //error
        alert.setView(input);
```

My error was:

> The method setText(CharSequence, TextView.BufferType) in the type EditText is not applicable for the arguments (TextView, TextView.BufferType)

It seems the generated EditText for the alert dialog does not take in set Text.

Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: The error says that that you are calling setText with a TextView and a TextView.BufferType as arguments.. How do you declare user_descript? Are you perhas using the wrong variable???

Comment: Read the error. You're trying to pass a `TextView` into a method that requires a `CharSequence`.